# Grid view data format in Sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I want to display some data in gridview format in sencha touch but i'm not able to find any control or any other way to achieve this.

I want my gridview should look like :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, you're right, there's no grid component delivered with touch. You'll have to use this user extension: https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid.

Mitchell Simoens works at Sencha, so I think you don't have to worry about the quality of this component.