# How to implement table view in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to implement table view in sencha

I want to display view with tabular format with vertical line

```
Column1    Column2   Column3

S.no        Name     Age

1           test1    23
2           test2    24
3           test3     25
```

Thanks

Comment: You might check out the [Ext.ux.touch.grid](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid) extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grid view data format in Sencha touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871461/grid-view-data-format-in-sencha-touch)

Answer (score 0):

You can use touch-grid package for this but this is available only with Sencha complete. So if you used sencha-complete then its easy to do this.